# How to show history of customer's orders in restaurnant ordering system

Tags: python

I am working on a project of making restaurant ordering system using basic concepts of python. I need to put a logic to store every ordered item of customer and show his order history.

I am beginner at programming so, i not able to think of a logic yet. Please help

Answer (score 1):

How about a `Person` class that has a variable of type `list` named `orders`.

Now you can `append` the orders list with an item if a person orders something.